# Namespaced API's and resource routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-routing

I have my API in a versioned namespace,

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :posts
  end
end
```

but now when I have my controller do a `redirect_to @post` I get a route error for `Post` because no routes are defined for it.

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    # ...
  end
end

undefined method `post_url' for #<Api::V1::PostsController:0x007fb9c5fc8858>
```

I know I can update my controller to redirect to the named route and its not the end of the world:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  if @post.save
    redirect_to api_v1_post_url(@post)
    # or redirect_to [:api, :v1, @post]
  else
    # ...
  end
end
```

Is there a way to make `redirect_to @post` automatically detect that it should be in the right api version (so rails works out to use `api_v1_post_url`)? I know I could overwrite `redirect_to` but really I want a namespace aware `url_for`, maybe rails provides some hooks for this?

Answer (score 13):

There are three options in Ruby on Rails router

**1. Namespaces**(something which are you using right now)

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :posts
  end
end
```

Controller: `app/controllers/api/v1/PostsController.rb`

Example URL Path: `example.com/api/v1/posts`

**2. Scope**(only sets the url path)

```
scope 'api/v1' do
 resources :posts
end
```

Controller: `app/controllers/PostsController.rb`

Example URL Path: `example.com/api/v1/posts`

**3. Module**(only sets the controller)

```
 scope module: 'api/v1' do
   resources :posts
 end
```

Controller: `app/controllers/api/v1/PostsController.rb`

Example URL Path: `example.com/posts`

As you may notice from above, all of three do something similar to what you want but not the way you want it.

the only workaround I can think of against using awkwardly long path helpers `api_v1_post_url` is to use named routes to shorten it.

```
namespace :api, :as => "a" do
  namespace :v1, :as => "1" do
    resources :posts
  end
end
```

so instead of `api_v1_post_url`

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  if @post.save
    redirect_to api_v1_post_url(@post)
  end
end
```

you can use little shorter `a_1_post_url`

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  if @post.save
    redirect_to a_1_post_url(@post)
  end
end
```

Lastly, I am afraid, I am not aware of any way to intelligently auto-detect namespacing in rails routing.

Hope it helps